# Multiple words query in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

For example: 
There is a column "*description*" in a Lucene document. Let's say the content of "*description*" is [`hello foo bar`]. I want a query [`hello f`], then the document should be hit, [`hello ff`]
or [`hello b`] should not be hit.

I use the programmatic way to create the `Query`, such as `PrefixQuery`, `TermQuery` were added to `BooleanQuery`, but they don't work as expected. `StandardAnalyzer` is used.

Test cases:

a): `new PrefixQuery(new Term("description", "hello f"))` -> 0 hit

b): `PhraseQuery query = new PhraseQuery();
    query.add( new Term("description", "hello f*") )` -> 0 hit

c): `PhraseQuery query = new PhraseQuery();
    query.add( new Term("description", "hello f") )` -> 0 hit

Any recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you show some code snippets ? This will help us to understand your problem much better .

Comment: Have you tried using org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParse to parse a query string such as "description: hello AND description: f*"?

Comment: @pabrantes "description: hello AND description: f*" is not expected, I want "hello" followed by "f".

Comment: @TheDarkKnight three cases added.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are passing multiple terms to one `Term` object . If you want all your search words to be prefix-found, you need to :

1. Tokenize the input string with your analyzer, it will split your search text "hello f" to "hello" and "f":

   TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream(null, new StringReader(searchText)); CharTermAttribute termAttribute = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

   List tokens = new ArrayList();
   while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
      tokens.add(termAttribute.toString());
   }
2. Put each token into `Term` object which in turn needs to be put in `PrefixQuery` and all `PrefixQueries` to `BooleanQuery`

EDIT: For example like this:

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

for(String token : tokens) {        
    booleanQuery.add(new PrefixQuery(new Term(fieldName, token)),  Occur.MUST);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adam! I already use your 1st way to analyzer. But 2nd way is not expected way.

Answer (score 0):

tried Ngram or EdgeNgram while indexing??

http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html